# Recalculate attribute on every change of another attribute in Core Data MO

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have an attribute in a Core Data Managed Object that I'm trying to update dependent on another attribute.

How can I implement a method that is called every time the original attribute is changed?

`awakeFromInsert` and `awakeFromFetch` obviously won't work.
I've seen [`keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/Articles/moIntegrating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002138-SW4) but I don't really understand how I could use it.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Let's say you've got two attributes: `foo`, and `bar`, with `bar` being calculated based on `foo`. For this, you need to implement the `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingBar` method:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingBar {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"foo"];
}
```

Now, every time `foo` changes, any objects bound to `bar` will update themselves.

Obviously, this wont do much good if you're caching the value of `bar`, since you need to actually recalculate and recache it. However, unless you're doing some seriously hardcore calculations to determine `bar`, you're really better off just calculating `bar` every time the `-bar` method is called.